# The remote server returned an error: (400) Bad Request with MVC3 Integrating Facebook API

Tags: facebook, asp.net-mvc-3

I am facing the 400 bed request error. When I integrate the Facebook API for publish the events on page With MVC3 wit Razor in this function "facebook.GetAccessToken(fcode)", When  passing the access-code that comes  in url after successfully login  ;